# L_TRANSACTIONID0 from CreateRecurringPayments is empty

Tags: paypal

I have this code:

$response = $this->Expresscheckout->CreateRecurringPayments($amount,$package_name);

if(!empty($response['L_TRANSACTIONID0'])){

and the weird thing is $response['L_TRANSACTIONID0'] is empty, however after I clear my browser's cache and perform the same action again, which is creating a monthly recurring profile, it's NOT empty and works fine. Any ideas? Obviously I don't want to force my user's to clear their cache, so what is happening here and any way around this?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using some sort of class library, or what?  I'd need to see the actual request and response getting generated to try and help.

Comment: I'm using expresscheckout.php which has the CreateRecurringPayments function.

Comment: Also the paypalfunctions.php which defines all the global variables and wrapper functions. function CreateRecurringPayments($amount,$package_name){
 
 $this->request = new Paypalrequest;
 $resArray = $this->request->CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile($amount,$package_name); and the CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile function is inside the paypalfunctions.php file.